# Textbox can contain letters but no numbers allowed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create textbox where you can enter your name.
If textbox is empty show error.
If textbox contain numbers show error.

In my sample it does show error when i have empty textbox and when i have numbers like Robert1. But it does not work when Text ends with a letter. If you write 1Robert, then it doesn't show error.

My code:

```
string vards = textBox1.Text;

// Empty or wrong format

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        label5.Text = "You didn't enter anything!";
    }
else
{
    foreach(char c in vards)
    {
        if (Char.IsNumber(c))
        {
            label5.Text = "Your name is incorrect!";
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess i just had to add break;

```
            if (Char.IsNumber(c))
                    {
                        label5.Text = "Your name is incorrect!";
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Yes, that solves your problem.  You should remove the question at the end of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

the loop produces a invalid result. it overwrites the content of `label5` each char of `label1` and the final result is only about the last char

```
// Empty or wrong format
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
{
    label5.Text = "You didn't enter anything!";
}
else
{
    bool onlyLetters = textBox1.Text.All(x => Char.IsLetter(x));

    if (!onlyLetters)
    {
        label5.Text = "Your name is incorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loop on every character in the text. There you are overwriting `label5.Text` always. So actually only the last character matters in your logic.

You can use this:

```
bool anyNumbers = textBox1.Text.Any(Char.IsDigit);
if(anyNumbers)
{
    label5.Text = "Your name is incorrect!";
}
```

Here without LINQ:

```
bool valid = true;
foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i just add break; ? Is it fine too? It does work but don't know if it's right :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var input = txtExample.Text;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
     if(input.Any(d => char.IsDigit(d) == false)
     {
          // Valid
     }
```

You could actually use Linq, not even use the `foreach` loop.  Keep in mind this is being done on the server side, if your in a web application you trigger a `PostBack`.  Which you may want to do that, so if it is web based, you should do it Client Side.